# How to update table (adding new column) in Magento mysql4 setup script

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade, script

Since couple of weeks I'm trying to understand Magento, it's structure, mechanisms and I'm stuck on scripts creating for example additional columns in tables.
In my `config.xml` script I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config >
< modules >
    < Inchoo_Orders >
        <version>0.0.0.3< /version>
    < /Inchoo_Orders>
< /modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Model</class>
enter preformatted text here          
  <resourceModel>inchoo_orders_resource</resourceModel>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <inchoo_orders_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Inchoo_Orders</module>
                <class>Inchoo_Orders_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </inchoo_orders_setup>
    </resources>
   ......
```

My Sql script name is: `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.0.2-0.0.0.3.php`

But it won't update table. What I'm doing wrong ?
Getting error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Inchoo_Orders_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in
>   /home/.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>   on line 234

If I change class to `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` not giving me any errors but also I can't see it work.

Comment: Please post the file path to `Inchoo_Orders_Model_Mysql4_Setup` and also the contents your upgrade script.

Comment: Find in `core_resource` table your module, delete it, again refresh page again.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh while that is also good advice, his error is stating that the class is not found

Comment: @Shawn `If I change class to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup not giving me any errors but also I can't see it work.`. So, I think we need to remove the module and refresh page.

Comment: Good point. I upvoted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql4 is actually deprecated. However, if your Mysql4_Setup file lives within the resource directory, you will need to change the class name to `Inchoo_Orders_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup`.

If you are just trying to update a table and not much else, you should be able to just change

```
<class>Inchoo_Orders_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
```

to

```
<class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
```

If you need some sort of custom functionality that will live in your own Setup class, create this file.

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
{
   //whatever needs to go in here
}
```

And remember to add this to your config.xml file:

```
<class>Inchoo_Orders_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
```

If you need instruction on how to actually update the table itself, let me know.

---

Based on our continued discussion in the comments, it has been determined that all you really want to do here is add an attribute programatically.

First things first, you do not need your install script should be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'offer_status', array(
    'type'         => 'int',
    'label'        => 'Offer Status',
    'input'        => 'select',
    'global'       => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'source'       => 'inchoo_orders/catalog_product_attribute_source_offer_status',
    'backend'      => '',
    'visible'      => true,
    'required'     => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default'      => '',
    'group'        => "General Information"
));
```

Then you need to create a source model for your attribute.

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Source_Offer_Status
{
    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Auto')),
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Enabled')),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Disabled')),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
            0 => Mage::helper('core')->__('Auto'),
            1 => Mage::helper('core')->__('Enabled'),
            2 => Mage::helper('core')->__('Disabled'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, no, I do not need more than just one column into the table.

Comment: I can't make it work :( don't know why, removed from core_resources inchoo_orders_setup and it still won't add column. Apparently I missed something .... will work on it ;)

Comment: Please post the contents of your install script

Comment: <?php
// Add an extra column to the eav/catalog_products table:
 
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
 
$installer->startSetup();
 
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/catalog_products'),
    'offer_status',
    array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        'comment' => 'Offer status'
    )
);
 
$installer->endSetup();

Comment: @RobertA. in looking at what you are doing here, I am wondering if you can tell me more about what you are hoping to accomplish. The reason I ask is that you want to add a column 'offer_status' to every attribute, regardless of whether it is a product attribute, category attribute, customer attribute, etc. It doesn't seem to make sense. I am hoping to get you going in the right direction.

Are you trying to create an attribute or do you have a valid reason to add Offer Status to every attribute in the system?

Comment: @RobertA.regardless of your reasoning, try this: `$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/attibute'), 'store_id', 'VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT \'Offer status\'');`

Comment: Wait a sec, I just noticed your comment `Add an extra column to the eav/catalog_products table`. Your script is adding a column to the eav_attribute table. This will add it to the proper table. `$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('catalog/eav_attribute'), 'store_id', 'VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT \'Offer status\'');`

Comment: However, what I gather from your code and comments is that you really just need to add an attribute, not a column.

Comment: In conclusion, I decided not to addColumn into product just attribute as you just said. But still not sure how should I do it :)
Attribute should be like a selection with 3 elements, Auto,Enabled,Disabled

Comment: See two comments above. You were referencing the wrong table and also the last argument being passed into `->addColumn()` was not correct.

Comment: I added attribute manually but I would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'offer_status', [
 'type' => 'int',
 'input' => 'select',
 'label' => 'Offer status',
 'sort_order' => 1000,
 'default' => 0,
 'required' => true,
 'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
   'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
   'option' => [
   'values' => [
   0 => 'Auto',
   1 => 'Enabled',
   2 => 'Disabled',]],
]);
Is that ok ?
(sorry for my silly questions I'm a beginner :))
Where should I insert it  or how should it be done properly ?

Comment: you don't need the `backend` model  `eav/entity_attribute_backend_array` for a select attribute.

Comment: Heheh I just found it like this on internet ;)

Comment: Gimme a sec, Ill format it properly and update my answer for you.

Comment: Answer updated above

Comment: Great thanks Shawn, so where should be the first part  placed ?
Second part as the class name suggests should be in /Inchoo/Orders/Model/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Source/Offer.php Right ?

Comment: No, that is a place holder for a model alias. Backend models are used for the the purpose of modifying a value when certain events occur. Leaving it blank should be exactly what you need.

Comment: Once the script is applied and attribute created, what if this script will be executed again ?

Comment: If you mean for the purposes of resetting the installation and removing the attribute so that you can do it all over again, you need to do two things. Remove the `inchoo_orders` record from the `core_resource` table. Delete from `eav_attribute` table the row which contains your attribute code `offer_status`. You should then be able to run it again.

Comment: Ok, got it ;) In regards to the script itself and it's location.
should it be in:/Inchoo/Orders/Model/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Source/Offer.‌​php
or should be in /Inchoo/Orders/Model/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Source/Offer/Status.‌​php ??

Comment: and where should i put installer ?

Comment: Almost correct. It should be Inchoo/Orders/Model/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Source/Off‌​er/Status.php. All you gotta do to figure out the file location is convert the underscores to forward slash and then add .php at the end.

Comment: It started to be clear now ;)
Yes but what about installer. This is the part I don't understand yet :)

Comment: Does your Inchoo_Orders module already have install/upgrade scripts located in inchoo_orders_setup?

Comment: Your config.xml file is showing me that your install file should be in 
`Inchoo/Orders/sql/inchoo_orders_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php`. Notice that I removed the extra 0. You should also remove the extra zero from the top of your config.xml

Comment: /Inchoo/Orders/sql/orders_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.0.0.3.php
should i change it to:
/Inchoo/Orders/sql/inchoo_orders_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.p‌​hp ??

Comment: Actually, no. Keep the name the same, just remove the extra 0. The way you have it named with `upgrade` in it is appropriate. I assume you already have one file with `install` in the name?

Comment: Nope, actually all I've had was upgrade but I'm asking about a folder name rather than file, you told me it should be "inchoo_orders_setup" while I've had "orders_setup", because I'm a beginner must ask for everything :)

Comment: This should work: `/Inchoo/Orders/sql/inchoo_orders_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.‌​p‌​hp`

inchoo_orders_setup is derived from the global resources node in your config.xml file. If you name it this way, it should work.

Comment: Will check it now. Thank you very much Shawn ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I messed up something :) won't add attribute :(